# Laravel and Images validation

Tags: laravel, image, validation

I have a little question about Laravel ...

I have a big form with which it is possible to send images.
I did a "PageStoreRequest" with my validation rules and everything works fine.

Depending on the length of the form, I would like that if an image is not valid, it is simply "deleted" (or "ignored") from the form and that the rest of the form is treated correctly ... So that the rest of the images are not to be sent again ...

I wonder if there is a method that would check a single field?
(like my Image Field)
And if it is not valid, delete it?
(knowing that the other fields must also pass to the Validator)

Thanks for your ideas :)

Answer (score 0):

You can validate image field.

```
        $request->validate([
            'image'      => 'mimes:jpeg,jpg,png'
        ]);
```

And then field is validated;

```
        if ($request->hasFile('image') && $request->file('image')->isValid()) {
            // Make something
        }
```

Comment: Thanks @smyldz,

But, can I "remove" or "ignore" the image field if !isValid() ?
My goal is to be able to save the other fields of the form without the image blocking the registration

Thanks again :)